# ReadImage() Not Working PHP and ImageMagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I am creating a viewer that can handle various image formats including HEIC.

The code below has been rewritten and reposted since the original question and oddly, it worked once or twice but now fails on readImage(). Maybe it's something as simple as a typo but if so I cannot spot it! The browser reports `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` even though the path and file exist.

I am running:

```
Ubuntu 21.04
Apache/2.4.46
PHP 7.4.16
ImageMagick 3.4.4 (built with HEIC support)
```

For testing purposes, the script below is being run directly in the browser. $fileDir includes the file name and full path back to the root /var

```
<?php include_once $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/internals/configuration/common.php";

$filePath = "Some Descriptive Text Here (Location)";
$fileName = "IMG_4039.HEIC";

// $SecurePath is a system-wide variable to the base folder
$fileDir = urldecode("{$SecurePath}verified/$filePath/$fileName");

if (file_exists($fileDir)) :
    $image = new Imagick();
    $image->readImage($fileDir);
    $type = $image->getImageFormat();
    if ($type === "heic") :
        $image->setImageFormat("png");
        header("Content-type: image/png");
    elseif ($type === "pdf") :
        $image->readImage('$fileDir[0]');
        $image = $image->flattenImages();
        $image->setImageFormat("jpeg");
        header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    else :
        header("Content-type: image/$type");
    endif;
    echo $image->getImageBlob();
else :
    echo "The file ($fileDir) cannot be found";
endif;

?>
```

Even with only these two lines it crashes which is why I think readImage() is not working properly. No errors with it and all below it remarked out.

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage($fileDir);
```

Output from `convert -version` confirms that HEIC support is installed and working and it also shows in `phpinfo()`:

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.9-8 Q16 x86_64 2021-08-11 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2020 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(4.5) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr png tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

There are several delegates.xml files but not sure which, if any, ImageMagick is using.

```
locate delegates.xml
/etc/ImageMagick-6/delegates.xml
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7/delegates.xml
/usr/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-7/www/source/delegates.xml
/usr/src/ImageMagick-7.0.9-8/config/delegates.xml
/usr/src/ImageMagick-7.0.9-8/config/delegates.xml.in
/usr/src/ImageMagick-7.0.9-8/www/source/delegates.xml

$ convert -list delegate
convert: error while loading shared libraries: libIlmImf-2_2.so.23: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: If the images all have appropriate filename extensions (or some other means to determine their type) you don't need ImageMagick at all. Just set the content type based on the extension and spit out the file contents with `readfile()`.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and I see I need to tweak the question a bit. I do need to convert the HEICs for display as they are not compatible with browsers and I understand that ImageMagick is the only game in town for converting them (my installation was built with HEIC support) but would be happy to know if it can be done in other ways. This seemed a good way to experiment with ImageMagick too. 

My script is currently somewhat mixed and matched since I started with an existing one so I want to rework it as much as possible to be consistent!

Comment: When you first receive the HEIC images, convert them once via imagick cli and then store them locally as PNG or whatever. You don't want to have to do that resource-intensive process over and over again for every request.

Comment: Thank you again but the way I'm planning on using this, which is only in an administration area of the site for my own access (so won't see any heavy use), even copying them and unless the original is deleted, the script will still need to load them.

Comment: You do know you are not running Imagemagick directly but via the php API? I always start with something simple/basic to make sure it is working before adding all the options. Dose viewer.php work if you run it directly? What does $file return?

Comment: Yes, I know and no, running it directly does not work either (I've been testing it both ways) although if I remark out much and just echo the file contents, it displays the image *gibberish* on the screen so it is loading the file. $file returns only the file name as it's a variable that is preassigned to a specific value that is temporarily hard-coded for testing purposes. It is a file and path that actually exists too.

Comment: Do you have libheic installed in your ImageMagick? What does `convert -version` return?

Comment: Yes, it is compiled with HEIC support as stated in the question. I'll append it to show the requested output.

Comment: If your file is HEIC, why does base64 decoding even come into your code?

Comment: I re-wrote the question and put in the latest code which worked briefly, then stopped. Maybe a typo? If so, I can't spot it!

Comment: If there is an entry for HEIC in the delegates.xml file, you may need to use the full path to HEIC in the DEVICE parameter.

Comment: I appended the question with delegates.xml details.